# Difference between self.object and self->object

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to know what is difference between `self.object` and `self->object`? how can we able to release memory in ARC using `self`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is a pointer, so `self->object` correctly references `object`.

`self.object` however is Objective-C *syntactic sugar* for `[self object]` and will call the getter method (`-(Object *)object`) (or the setter method `[self setObject:]` if you are assigning).

If you are using ARC then you don't explicitly need to do anything to release memory.

Answer (score 0):

`self.object` calls the setter method, which does memory management such as retaining the object. `self->object` sets/accesses the object directly which doesn't do any memory management.  Generally you wouldn't want to access an object's ivar directly, so just create setters/getters for `object` and use `self.object`.